# Freebase dotNet API CreateRequest

Tags: .net, google-api, freebase

I'm using dotNet Freebase API(googleapi). [This](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Topic_API) wikipage shows that Topic API is a simple and useful way to fetch data which is just what I want. But I can't find any relevant methods in dotNet Freebase API, I can just find methods with MQL, image and text...

I also noticed that there is a method called `CreateRequest(string resource, string method)`. But when I tried to assign resource="https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/0d6lp" and method="GET", it throws KeyNotFoundException...

Is it possible to use CreateRequest method to fetch data? If yes, what value should I assign to variable *resource* and variable *method*? If no, what's the usage of this method?